# My autoformat color-schemes are not working correctly on my gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In the design view, it updates just fine, but some reason when I compile, it's extremely washed out and barely readable. Any idea why? Attached is the parameters to my gridview and a screen shot. I currently have the autumn option for auto format, so the header row should be a dark red, but instead I get this!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIUzF.jpg]

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdInspections" runat="server" OnRowEditing="grdInspections_RowEditing" AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        DataSourceID="ldsInspections" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="75px">
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />

        <Columns>
        ...
```

Comment: Are you using any other style sheets on the site?  My guess is the <a> tags visited or an overide by another style. Remove all style sheets and try again. I always use CSSClass on the rowstyle, headerstyle, pagerstyle, selectedrowstyle, etc. that way you can globally change if you have gridviews on one or more pages.

Comment: I just commented out me entire style sheet and the result remains the same.

Comment: I've also exported all the styling to a CSS class and using both the CSS class and commenting out everything else on the style sheet, the background is STILL that washed out color. However, the header links changed to a blue color now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the only way it seems I'm able to alter the colors on this datagrid is by making a css class and then applying that to each column as a HeaderStyle-CssClass. But using a Headerstyle in the datagrid with and without a css class does not work. For now, I'm just going to copy and paste this headerStyle Css Class to each column, but there are like 30 of them so if anyone could maybe help me out with why this won't work in the headserstyle of the datagrid?

```
.gHeaderStyle {
    color: #FFFFCC;
    background-color: #990000;
}

.gHeaderStyle a:link { 
    color: #FFFFCC;
}
```